# What does heap initialization mean?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am doing a coding assignment for a data structure class. I basically have to implement different sorting algorithms (Selection Sort, QuickSort, etc..) and compare the running time.

However, on the instruction, it says I have to implement two different heap sorting algorithms. Here is the instruction:

> 1. heapsort, without using `heap initialization' (i.e., by inserting the numbers repeatedly into
>      an initially empty heap)
> 2. heapsort using heap initialization

Here, I am not sure what heap initialization mean. I tried to google it, but I could not find any source that would explain well. What does it mean by implementing a heap sort with/without heap initialization?

I am coding in java for reference!

Thanks

Comment: These are different methods to build up the heap out of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is how you get the initial heap.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap (Building a heap section).

There's William's method where you insert elements one by one into a heap (initially empty). This one is O(NlogN). This one is the non-initialized version.

There's Floyd's version where you take the array and make some swaps to make it a heap. This one will be O(N) (check wikipedia for the math). Pseudocode available on wikipedia.

Overall the complexity is driven by the extraction process which is O(NlogN).

Comment: Aha, I see. Thank you for answering.